# clojure - combine to structures to get flatter result

Tags: clojure

I am trying to combine 2 structures:

```
(def acc [[1]])
```

and

```
(def pairs '((2 4)))
```

I want the following result:

```
'((1 2) (1 4))
```

I have tried the following:

```
(map-indexed
  (fn [idx pair]
    (map (fn [itm]
      (concat (nth acc idx) (vector itm))) pair)) pairs)
```

But this gives:

```
(((1 2) (1 4)))
```

I could call first but this falls apart as bigger lists are attempted.

For example if I had

```
(def acc '((1 2) (1 4)))
```

and

```
(def pairs '((5 1) (1 4)))
```

I want to the result to be:

```
'((1 2 5) (1 2 1) (1 4 1) (1 4 4))
```

Comment: It is not clear what behavior you expect for "bigger lists". Also, your code as posted will not compile (`acc` not resolvable).

Comment: @A.Webb I have updated the question, let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an algorithm that takes two input sequences of sequences and does this:

1. Take one sequence from each input sequence so that you have two sequences, `s1` and `s2`
2. For each `elem` in `s2` produce a sequence of `s1` with `elem` appended to it
3. Repeat 1. until one of the two input sequences has no more sequences left

In Clojure:

```
(mapcat (fn [s1 s2]
           (map (fn [elem]
                  (conj s1 elem)) s2))
        acc pairs)
```

Comment: When I run that on @dagda1's `acc` and `pairs` it puts the item they want last at the head of the list. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: This is true. He has provided one example of `acc` as a vector and another as list. I have decided to write the implementation for the vector version as appending values to vectors has better performance characteristics.

Comment: Ah, yes, there is one with a vector -- I only ran it on the list version. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

When mapping over nested data structures, `for` is often simpler.

```
user> 
(defn unfolder
  [acc pairs]
  (for [combination (map list acc pairs)
        tail (second combination)]
    (conj (vec (first combination)) tail)))

#'user/unfolder
user> (unfolder '((1 2) (1 4)) '((5 1) (1 4)))
([1 2 5] [1 2 1] [1 4 1] [1 4 4])
```

Comment: item is missing a level of nesting.  (for [pair '((2 4)) element pair items [[1]] item items] [item element])

Comment: I've updated the question, I don't think I can use for with the second example.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: your algorithm requires appending to collections - it is better to use a collection type that supports fast access to the back (like a `vector`)

```
(def acc '([1 2] [1 4])) ;; notice the inner collections are vectors
(def pairs '([5 1] [1 4]))

(defn zipp
  [c1 c2]
  (mapcat (fn [c3 c4]
            (map (partial conj c3) c4)) ;; change this line for lists!
          c1
          c2))

(zipp acc pairs)
;; => ([1 2 5] [1 2 1] [1 4 1] [1 4 4])
```

If you must work with `list`'s, you can change the line marked above to:

```
(map (partial conj (into [] c3)) c4))
```

It's rather ugly, IMO.